# Doesn't apply the TinyMCE editor to the text area in asp using Html helpers

Tags: asp.net, tinymce

I'm creating an asp gadget and trying to add tinymce text editor to the text area. But it doesn't appear the editor .So the added code is as follows, Input Fields are showing in the view but doesn't appear the editor

```html
<script src="JavaScripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="JavaScripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js" ></script>
 
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Initialize your tinyMCE Editor with your preferred options
    tinyMCE.init({
        // General options
        mode: "textareas",
        theme: "modern",
        // Theme options
        theme_advanced_buttons1: "save,newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
        theme_advanced_buttons2: "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
        theme_advanced_buttons3: "tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,emotions,iespell,media,advhr,|,print,|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen",
        theme_advanced_buttons4: "insertlayer,moveforward,movebackward,absolute,|,styleprops,spellchecker,|,cite,abbr,acronym,del,ins,attribs,|,visualchars,nonbreaking,template,blockquote,pagebreak,|,insertfile,insertimage",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_location: "top",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_align: "left",
        theme_advanced_statusbar_location: "bottom",
        theme_advanced_resizing: true,
 
        // Example content CSS (should be your site CSS)
        content_css: "css/example.css",
    });
    </script>
 
<div class="form">
    <%=Html.Partial("Menu") %><br /><br />
        <% Html.BeginGadgetForm("Update"); %>
        <label for="message">Title :</label>
     <%= Html.TextBox("updatedTitle",Model.Title %>
        <label for="message">Message :</label>
        <%= Html.TextAreaFor("updatedName",x=>x.Message %>
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<%= Model.Id %>" />
         <input type="submit" value="Update" />
    <% Html.EndForm(); %>
</div>
```

The Text area doesn't apply the tinymce editor

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the tinyMCE class and name to the text field:

```
TextMode="MultiLine" class="myTextEditor" name="tinymce"
```

Comment: Tried it.But not working .I'm using this view inside an asp user controller.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you got this working in the end...but I had tons of trouble getting the tinyMCE working. Followed loads of posts to the letter and no joy. In the end I found a post with a simple example that finally worked. No idea what it was about the particular post that was different but do notice you have *mode* specifying textareas and this example has *selector* specifying textarea. Just in case it helps you or anyone else who comes across this the question, the below code is working for me:

```
<div class="textarea mce-tinymce">
            <script type="text/javascript">
                tinymce.init({ 
                    selector: "textarea",
                    theme: "modern",
                    plugins: [
                        "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
                        "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen",
                        "insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality",
                        "emoticons template paste textcolor colorpicker textpattern imagetools"
                    ],
                    toolbar1: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image",
                    toolbar2: "print preview media | forecolor backcolor emoticons",
                    image_advtab: true,
                    templates: [
                        { title: 'Test template 1', content: 'Test 1' },
                        { title: 'Test template 2', content: 'Test 2' }
                    ]
                });
            </script>
            @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.BlogPost)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BlogPost)
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

first be sure the java link is correct

```
 <script src="../tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>
```

second add new java item and add this code

```
  tinyMCE.init({
       // General options
       mode: "textareas",
       theme: "advanced",
       plugins: "safari,pagebreak,style,layer,table,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template,inlinepopups",

       // Theme options
       theme_advanced_buttons1: "newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
       theme_advanced_buttons2: "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
       theme_advanced_buttons3: "tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,emotions,iespell,media,advhr,|,print,|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen",
       theme_advanced_buttons4: "insertlayer,moveforward,movebackward,absolute,|,styleprops,|,cite,abbr,acronym,del,ins,attribs,|,visualchars,nonbreaking,template,pagebreak",
       theme_advanced_toolbar_location: "top",
       theme_advanced_toolbar_align: "left",
       theme_advanced_statusbar_location: "bottom",
       theme_advanced_resizing: true,

       // Example word content CSS (should be your site CSS) this one removes paragraph margins
       content_css: "css/word.css",

       // Drop lists for link/image/media/template dialogs
       template_external_list_url: "lists/template_list.js",
       external_link_list_url: "lists/link_list.js",
       external_image_list_url: "lists/image_list.js",
       media_external_list_url: "lists/media_list.js",

       // Replace values for the template plugin
       template_replace_values: {
           username: "me",
           staffid: "991234"
       }
   });
```

i named this file TMS

```
<script src="../tiny_mce/utils/TMS.js"></script>
```

and add the first java link and the second links to your code like this

```
<script src="../tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>
<script src="../tiny_mce/utils/TMS.js"></script>
```

now how we can add editor to textbox :

```
<asp:TextBox ID="T25" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="532px"></asp:TextBox>
```

thanx